# What happened to PostgreSQL10Dialect in Hibernate 6.x?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Before migrating to Spring boot 3, we were using the PostgreSQL10Dialect in our apps.
When migrating to Spring boot 3, I realized that Hibernate 6 no longer includes PostgreSQL10Dialect. I cannot find any mention of this [in the Hibernate 6 migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc).

What are we supposed to switch to? PostgreSQL95Dialect ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I realized that Hibernate 6 no longer includes `PostgreSQL10Dialect`.

So this is actually a mistake, it was supposed to have been left there as a deprecated stub to smooth migration, but it accidentally got deleted. (I will put it back for Hibernate 6.2.)

But anyway, you don't need it. In Hibernate 6:

- you don't usually need to explicitly specify a dialect, the right `Dialect` is almost always chosen automatically, and
- we have moved away from "versioned" dialects, so the right dialect to use is just `PostgreSQLDialect`.

Comment: Thanks, great to get some clarity on this!

Comment: Both `PostgreSQL10Dialect` and `PostgreSQLDialect` generate warnings when using the H2 database is Postgres mode. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17032.

Comment: I have read that you want to add the postgres10 dialect again, but it is not included in Hibernate 6.4.4. The included Postgres dialect only supports 12 or higher. We have some databases running on version 10. How do you get them to run with Hibernate 6.x?