# Spring boot 3 hibernate 6.1 migration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm migrating a service to Spring boot 3.0 and Hibernate 6.1 from hibernate 5 and spring 2.7. I can't figure out how to migrate the following code.
I know they removed PostgreSQL10Dialect and now I can use PostgreSQLDialect.
Can anyone suggest how can I migrate this code?

```
public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {
  public PGDialect() {
    super();
    registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "text[]");
    registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "text[]");
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think, here is the answer of your question [what-happened-to-postgresql10dialect-in-hibernate-6-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74744188/what-happened-to-postgresql10dialect-in-hibernate-6-x)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually, this fixed the issue for me now when I set ddl-auto: create-drop it works it can create the tables.
Some clarification I need to specify the dialect because PostgreSQL doesn't support arrays. Also we are using this library:
https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils
Here is the solution.

```
public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    @Override
    protected void registerColumnTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        DdlTypeRegistry ddlTypeRegistry = typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getDdlyTypeRegistry();
        ddlTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(new DdlTypeImpl(2003, "text[]", this));
        super.registerColumnTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```